# a formula about Pochhammer symbols

Tags: estimation

The Pochhammer formula reads
$$(a)_n=a (a+1)\cdots (a+n-1)=\Gamma(a+n) /\Gamma(a)$$

Here I want to rewrite a Pochhammer formula and my formula is:
$$(N(\alpha+1))_{(\beta-\alpha)n)}~~~~~~~~~~~~~*$$

Can I rewrite Eq.~(*) to a formula, like $(---)_n$? I just want that the subscript is only a function of $n$.

Any suggestion is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Are \beta, \alpha, and n integers?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson   n is an integer and  $\beta$ and $\alpha$ are not.

Comment: If $\beta-\alpha=1$, the Eq.~(*) is what I am looking for. Here  $\beta-\alpha<1$ with $\alpha>-1$.

Comment: I don't think its possible in general. You can really derive all Pochhammer identities with really two formulas i.e. the gamma reflection formula and $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$. I don't see hoe either will give you what you want. You may also want to look at the gamma duplication formula and its generalization.  Good luck.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson  Tanks， this method is not easy to perform. So I choose the saddle point method to calculate this.